# com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException:Error code: 393238 |Buffer overflow,no available space

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My app gets crashed in my offline wallpaper app. 
I'm getting a message in LogCat is:

> com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException:Error code: 393238 |Buffer overflow,no available space

any help, please?

Its offline app so it doesn't use the internet to access the wallpaper.

MainActivity

```
package com.jimdo.saifstudios.miniwallpack;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button bt_image1, bt_image2, bt_image3, bt_image4, bt_image5, bt_image6, 
bt_image7, bt_image8,
        bt_image9, bt_image10, bt_image11, bt_image12, bt_image13, 
bt_image14, bt_image15,
        bt_image16;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bt_image1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image1);
    bt_image2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image2);
    bt_image3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image3);
    bt_image4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image4);
    bt_image5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image5);
    bt_image6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image6);
    bt_image7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image7);
    bt_image8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image8);
    bt_image9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image9);
    bt_image10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image10);
    bt_image11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image11);
    bt_image12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image12);
    bt_image13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image13);
    bt_image14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image14);
    bt_image15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image15);
    bt_image16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_image16);



    bt_image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "camelb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //2
    bt_image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "mib";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //3
    bt_image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "lighthouseb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //4

    bt_image4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "deerb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //5
    bt_image5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "nightb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    //6
    bt_image6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "deertob";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //7
    bt_image7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "mountainb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //8
    bt_image8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "nightseab";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //9
    bt_image9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "snowfallb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //10
    bt_image10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "spaceb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //11
    bt_image11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "sunnyb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //12
    bt_image12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "sunnyseab";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //13

    bt_image13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "villageb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //14
    bt_image14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "desertb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //15
    bt_image15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "nightmoonb";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //16
    bt_image16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThemeActivity.class);
            String pathPic = "lighthouseseab";
            i.putExtra("PATH_PICTURE", pathPic);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

   }
}
```

ThemeActivity

```
package com.jimdo.saifstudios.miniwallpack;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ThemeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout theme_preview;
Button back_btn, save_btn;
String newString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_theme);

    theme_preview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.theme_preview);
    save_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    back_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            newString = null;
        } else {
            newString = extras.getString("PATH_PICTURE");

            if(newString.equals("camelb")) {
                theme_preview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.camelb);
            } else if(newString.equals("mib2")) {
                theme_preview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mib);
            } else {
                //write the statement.
            }
        }
    }

    back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jimdo.saifstudios.miniwallpack">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ThemeActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```